# How to prevent Silverstripe from changing URLSegment field value to lower case?

Tags: validation, silverstripe

I have an URLSegment field in my Silverstripe CMS, and I want to have a link there with upper case. But after saving, Silverstripe changes it to a lower case string. I can't find, where this behavior is triggered. Does anyone know, how to prevent that?

Comment: sure you know about the implications of capital letters in urls? http://wiredimpact.com/blog/never-use-capital-letters-urls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `URLSegmentFilter` [is responsible for the lower case conversion of the URLSegment](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-URLSegmentFilter.html#56-86), it calls [`mb_strtotlower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php). `URLSegmentFilter` is invoked in the `SiteTreeURLSegmentField` via [`Sitetree`'s `generateURLSegment` function](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-SiteTree.html#1678-1700).

The important part to take away from this is that the `generateURLSegment` function actually invokes Silverstripe's extension system so if you do a data extension of `SiteTree`, you just need to specify a function called `updateURLSegment` and do your own processing on top of what Silverstripe does.

From the code I linked above, the first argument passed into your `updateURLSegement` function would be the filtered (and lower case) version of the URL, the second argument would be the untouched value.

When doing this, I would be careful to make sure that you re-implement all the other filtering code like the `URLSegmentFilter` does (minus the lower case call) otherwise it will likely break the system with invalid characters.

A side note to this, I would be wary of actually doing this change. Having varied case in a URL isn't helpful to anyone, some users will think the URLs are case sensitive and for some systems it quite easily could be. I don't know whether Silverstripe would have that issue though, I haven't come across it with the varied projects I have worked on or helped people with.

One more quick thing, there is another method to implement a similar change using Silverstripe's [`Object::useCustomClass` function](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Object.html#295-310) and override `URLSegmentFilter` entirely though only use that as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and very informative answer. I tried the solution with extending the `SiteTree`, but that didn't help, because the `filter` function of the `URLSegmentFilter` (with the `mb_strtolower` function) is also called in `onBeforeWrite()` of `SiteTree`, so my `updateURLSegment` function wasn't triggered when editing the URLSegment field in the CMS. That's why I had to use `Object::useCustomClass` and extend `URLSegmentFilter` in my new class with an overriden `filter` function.

Comment: Ahhhh OK, glad you got it working. That is useful to know about about it being called in the `onBeforeWrite` too, didn't pick that up myself :)